# How can I implement the reverse ajax like comet or Websync in asp.net simple web pages

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery, webmethod

How  can I implement the reverse ajax like comet or Websync in asp.net simple web pages?
I want to get push the updates on server then reverse the response on all clients with in a second.
Because I'm new and don't have any idea about the reverse ajax ?

Comment: Put more effort on asking question. Put some scenario what your have tried or what you have searched for.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [WebSync](http://frozenmountain.com/products/websync). It uses the Bayeux protocol (so you can integrate with solutions from other vendors), uses WebSockets when available, supports web browsers back to IE 5.5, and has client SDKs for just about every software platform.

Have your clients subscribe to a channel (e.g. '/data'):

```
var client = new fm.websync.client('websyncurl');
client.connect();
client.subscribe({ channel: '/data', onReceive: function(e) {
    alert(e.getData());
});
```

Then when you want to send something from the server:

```
WebSyncServer.Publish("/data", Json.Serialize(data));
```

**Disclaimer:** I work for [Frozen Mountain](http://www.frozenmountain.com).

Answer (score 1):

Use SignalR http://signalr.net/ it enables to push content to client

Comment: On http://www.asp.net/signalr you have tutoriak for as.net and asp.net mvc for creating chat using signalr

Answer (score 0):

**SignalR** works well with **MVC**, and the Chat Application they use in the sample is MVC.  As pointed out by @Garath, there's a tutorial to follow on ASP.NET.  Another technology to consider is **Knockout**, they work well together with the instant updates to the UI.  I have just finished a messageboard type application using Knockout, MVC and SignalR and it works really well.

http://knockoutjs.com/

There's a TODO application here which implements the mentioned technologies also, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/322154/ASP-NET-MVC-SIngalR-and-Knockout-based-Real-time-U